# How to mock Files.copy method in JUnit

Tags: spring, junit4

I am using some of the methods of `Files` class like (delete, copy methods) to do upload and delete of file. Below is the code to perform these operations.

```
public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {
    try {
    String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename()
        // Copy file to the target location (Replacing existing file with the same name)
        Path targetLocation = Paths.get("uploadPath" + File.separator + StringUtils.cleanPath(fileName));
        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), targetLocation, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        return fileName;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new FileStorageException("Not able to upload", ex);
    }
}
```

But for this source code I am not able to write JUnit tests because not able to mock `Files` class. For mocking final classes we can use PowerMock which supports to mock static and final methods. But here if I do using PowerMock still it is not mocking. I am using Spring Framework 5.2.1.RELEASE , Is there any change in JUnit with this version to mock final classes or methods? Or can any one help me on writing the unit tests for this code (versions I am using Spring Framework 5.2.1 and JUnit4.12).

Answer (score 0):

Mocking static and final classes is indeed possible only with tools like PowerMock or PowerMockito, and its not related to JUnit or Spring frameworks.

I think you should not Mock `Files.copy` operation.
Instead consider the following strategy:

Define an interface for working with files, a kind of DAO but for file system:

```
public interface FileSystemDAO {
   void copy(InputStream is, Path target, StandardCopyOption ... options);
}

public class FileSystemDAOImpl implements FileSystemDAO {
    void copy(InputStream is, Path target, StandatadCopyOption ... options) {
      Files.copy(...)
    }
}
```

Now use dependency injection in all the places that work with files (if you're using spring as you've said - define `FileSystemDAOImpl` as a bean).

```
class MySampleUploadService {

 private final FileSystemDAO fileSystemDao;

 public MySampleUploadService(FileSystemDAO dao) {
      this.fileSystemDao = dao;
 }
 public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {
     try {
     String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename()
         // Copy file to the target location (Replacing existing file with the same name)
         Path targetLocation = Paths.get("uploadPath" + File.separator + 
 StringUtils.cleanPath(fileName));
         fileSystemDao.copy(file.getInputStream(), targetLocation, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        return fileName;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new FileStorageException("Not able to upload", ex);
    }
 }

}
```

Now with this approach you can easily test the Upload service by mocking the `FileSystemDao` interface.